# Show Model In Full Page from Visual-force Tab in lightning console

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I have a requirement to open a Model box from a visualforce tab in the lighting console app.
My model is stuck inside the console tab and not opening in the full window.

below is the code that I used for the model and I am opening this popup inside visualforce page

```
<template>
<template if:true={showPopup}>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_small"
        aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header" style="padding-bottom: 0;">
                //code for header
            </header>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-var-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-box">
                    <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={modelContent.content}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" onmousedown={closeModel}></div>
</template>
```

Actual Output:

[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: Which modal code did you use? Using this still works fine https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/modal-popup-lightning-component-salesforce/. I remember there was an update regarding this. But I think it apples only if you using `overlay library`, i guess.

Comment: @NagendraSingh, I have updated my code for model

Answer (score 0):

So as per my understanding, your VFPage might be inside an `iframe` as it is in Lightning console.

As the component is getting created in an iframe it might open on full screen.

To open on full screen, have a utility bar and add an LWC component wrapped inside an aura component in that, add a listener here (LMS or `message` event). From VF Page just post a message `event` to LWC component with all required attributes and open the modal from LWC.
Then it should open on full page.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I have tried this before posting it, but for the popup, we don't want to add a utility bar for all the customers. so I was wondering if there is any other solution to how the popup out of the iframe.

Comment: There is another solution, you can have a hidden LWC component in page itself disgused as a listener, same as utility bar, the only extra thing there would be, you will have to make sure when the message is triggered only the current tab listens to it by passing some parameter, like tab id.